# How to detect unusual queries (injection suspicious) before runing it?

Tags: php, mysql, string, code-injection

Some hackers have access to my database and i am going to find the bug; i have not access to server logs.
I made this code for saving suspicious queries on a text file :

```
function query($query) {
$file = 'sqllog.txt';
if(/* Which condition should i use to detect? */){
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$contents.="\r\n";
$contents.=$query;
file_put_contents($file,$contents);
}
$this->theQuery = $query;
return mysql_query($query, $this->link);
}
```

Which condition should i use to detect sql injection suspicious queries?

Comment: If you're looking for a pattern you should log all queries and then review for common patterns.

Comment: Just escape the variables you use in your mysql queries.

Comment: Is it possible to detect queries that contain keywords like :"union"

Comment: you can use strpos($query,'union'); if $query variable contains any 'union' then a numeric value is returned else returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look for non-sanitized inputs (i.e. no use of `mysql_real_escape_string`) in your codebase. Ideally call this function right before inserting the parameters into your queries.

Alternatively, consider switching to prepared statements using PDO and SQL injection will no longer be an issue.